# Reference own item field in find query

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb

I cannot find how to make this query : find from items collection object that have at least one item in their list2 whose src.value field is not in their .list1.

example of what i want to match :

```
{ list1: ["FOO"], list2: [ {src: { value: "BAR" }} ]}
```

And I cannot do it with $expr and a JS function since the DB is on AWS DocumentDB.

Can't you do something like this pseudo query ? :

```
.find({ "src.value": { $nin:  "$.list1" }})
```